# Como agregar un aestructura JSON al Textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando un programa que modifique los valores de un `textarea` en formato `JSON` mediante la actualización de un `form`.

Hasta ahora, he conseguido obtener los valores de los `input` del `form`, e imprimirlos por consola gracias al bucle `for`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es, como habréis visto en la imagen de ejemplo, tras obtener los datos de los `input`, insertarlos dentro del textarea con un formato `JSON`, tal que así:

```
[
   {
      "title": "Tariff 2.0 A",
      "power":
      [
         {
            "type": "P1",
            "value": "0,115187"//€/kW día
         }
      ],
      "energy":
      [
         {
            "type": "P1",
            "value": "0,135308"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Dejo aquí la máquina y su funcionamiento:

```js
var jotason = [
   {
      "title": "Tariff 2.0 A",
      "power":
      [
         {
            "type": "P1",
            "value": "0,115187"//€/kW día
         }
      ],
      "energy":
      [
         {
            "type": "P1",
            "value": "0,135308"
         }
      ]
   }
];

//      BTN ADD BUTTON V_POWER

function addPower() {
   var power = document.getElementById("power");
   //aquí agregamos el componente de tipo input
   var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   //aquí indicamos que es un input de tipo text
   input.type = 'text';
   input.name = 'v_power';
   
   //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
   power.appendChild(input);
}


//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_ENERGY
function addEnergy()    {
   var energy = document.getElementById("energy");
   //aquí agregamos el componente de tipo input
   var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   //aquí indicamos que es un input de tipo text
   input.type = 'text';
   input.name = 'v_energy';
   
   //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
   energy.appendChild(input);
}


//    BTN LECTURA VALORES INPUT

function sndFrm()   {
//    Numerar cuántos input hay y pasarlos por variable

   var pnum = document.getElementsByName('v_power');
   var ptnum = pnum.length;
   var vnum = document.getElementsByName('v_energy');
   var vtnum = vnum.length;

//    Solo habrá un tipo por cada tarifa, por tanto no hace falta entrar en bucle

   var tPower = document.getElementsByName('t_power')[0].value;
   var tEnergy = document.getElementsByName('t_energy')[0].value;

   console.log(tPower + ' ' + tEnergy);

//    Bucle for para contar el número de input v_power que hay e imprimir todos sus valores

   for(i=0;i<ptnum;i++) {
      var vPower = document.getElementsByName('v_power')[i].value;
      console.log(vPower);
}

//    Bucle for para contar el número de input v_energy que hay e imprimir todos sus valores  
   for(i=0;i<vtnum;i++) {
      var vEnergy = document.getElementsByName('v_energy')[i].value;
      console.log(vEnergy);
   }

   document.getElementById('txtare').innerHTML=tPower + ' ' + tEnergy;
   txtedt();
}



//    Obtener el valor del textarea
function copyPaste() {
   var txtAr = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;

   console.log(txtAr);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Tarif</label>
        <input type="text" name="tarif">
<br>
            <label>Power</label>
        <div id="power">
            <input type="text" name="t_power">
            <input type="text" name="v_power">
            <button type="button" onclick="addPower()">+</button>
        </div>
<br>
            <label>Energy</label>
        <div id="energy">
            <input type="text" name="t_energy">
            <input type="text" name="v_energy">
            <button type="button" onclick="addEnergy()">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="sndFrm()">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
</form>
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->


    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
    <br>
<textarea id="txtare" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    
</textarea>
    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
<button type="button" onclick="copyPaste()">UPDATE FORM</button>

</body>
</html>
```

En el propio ejemplo, podréis ver dos funciones distintas `onclic` que añaden más input con valor `v_power` o `v_energy` al formulario. Tendría que ser una manera en la que, al añadir más, en el `textarea` también se añadiesen más campos.

(Solo uso javascript, no utilizo ningún otro framework)

Comment: Tu pregunta me parece confusa. No sé si buscas algo parecido a [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) ¿?

Comment: Perdón, peco de explicarme mal cuando lo tengo metido en mi cabeza. La cosa es, que cuando yo hago un cambio en el formulario, por ejemplo, le asigno un valor  a un campo, cuando le doy al botón de actualizar textarea, el propio valor cambie en el textaerea. Y tengo entendido que eso se consigue haciendo que el propio textarea tenga asignada una estructura JSON. Si hay alguna otra forma, por favor dimela, porque me voy a volver loco.

Comment: No hay por qué volverse loco. Hay mil formas de hacer las cosas en programación. Algo muy importante es saber explicar lo que quieres hacer, a veces uno no encuentra solución a un problema ¡porque no sabe explicar ese problema! Explicándolo, a veces incluso das con la solución. Y si no das con ella te ayudaremos por aquí, pero es necesario que entendamos lo que quieres, que muestres lo que has intentado y que digas: tengo tal problema o error en esta parte del código. O, si hay mejores formas te diremos, esto puedes hacerlo también así, o existe tal herramienta para esto, etc.

Comment: Lo intentaré, editaré la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo conseguí con ayuda de un compeñaro:

```js
//      BTN ADD BUTTON V_POWER

function addPower() {
   var power = document.getElementById("power");
   //aquí agregamos el componente de tipo input
   var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   //aquí indicamos que es un input de tipo text
   input.type = 'text';
   input.name = 'v_power';
   
   //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
   power.appendChild(input);
}


//       BTN ADD BUTTON V_ENERGY
function addEnergy()    {
   var energy = document.getElementById("energy");
   //aqui agregamos el componente de tipo input
   var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
   //aqui indicamos que es un input de tipo text
   input.type = 'text';
   input.name = 'v_energy';
   
   //y por ultimo agreamos el componente creado al padre
   energy.appendChild(input);
}


//    BTN LECTURA VALORES INPUT

function sndFrm()   {
//    Numerar cuantos input hay y pasarlos por variable


   

   var jotason = [];
   document.body.querySelectorAll(".templatecARD").forEach(form=>{

         let obj = {
            title : form.querySelector(".name_tarif").value
         };
         // power
         let power = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.type=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_power]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var ob = power[index]||{};
            ob.value=inpt.value;
            power[index]=ob;
         });
         
         // energy
         let energy = {};
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=t_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.type=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         form.querySelectorAll("input[name=v_energy]").forEach((inpt, index)=>{
            var oj = energy[index]||{};
            oj.value=inpt.value;
            energy[index]=oj;
         });
         obj.power = power;
         obj.energy = energy;
         jotason.push(obj);

   });

   var jsoned = JSON.stringify(jotason,undefined, 2);
   document.getElementById('txtare').value=jsoned;
}



//    Obtener el valor del textarea

/*
function copyPaste() {
   var txtAr = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;

   console.log(txtAr);
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<form method="post">
    <div class="templatecARD" data-group="0" >
        <label>Tarif</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif"/>
<br/>
            <label>Power</label>

        <div id="power">
            <input type="text" name="t_power"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_power"/>
            <button type="button" onclick="addPower()">+</button>
        </div>
<br/>
            <label>Energy</label>

        <div id="energy">
            <input type="text" name="t_energy"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_energy"/>
            <button type="button" onclick="addEnergy()">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<br>
    <button type="button" onclick="sndFrm()">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
</form>
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->


    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
    <br>
<textarea id="txtare" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></textarea>
    <!-- EDITOR DE JSON -->
<button type="button" onclick="copyPaste()">UPDATE FORM</button>

</body>
</html>
```